# Cut a string if some string starts with a specific word and ends with a string in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have string `Version="10.1.1"`. I want to get only `10.1.1`. This means I need to the string which start `Version="` and ends with `"`:

```
FINDSTR /I "^Version=" C:\version.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking to run your command through a `For` loop in your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

To learn how to do that, please open a Command Prompt window, *(`cmd.exe`)*, then enter `for /?`, to read through its output.

Here are two examples:

Using the **`=`** as a delimiter and variable expansion to remove the surrounding quotes:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('FindStr /I "^Version=" "C:\version.txt" 2^>NUL')Do @Set "Ver=%%~B"
@Echo(%%Ver%% = %Ver% & Pause
```

Using the **`"`** as a delimiter:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('FindStr /I "^Version=" "C:\version.txt" 2^>NUL')Do @Set "Ver=%%A"
@Echo(%%Ver%% = %Ver% & Pause
```